# How can I fill out border boxes to align text horizontally using Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row border border-success">
  <div class="cols-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4" class="border border-info">
    <header class="h4 border border-primary">
      Some header text
    </header>
    <div class="border border-danger">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas feugiat vitae lacus eget pretium. Donec vel
      mauris lorem. Vivamus massa enim, lacinia et lorem vel, porta viverra orci. Maecenas sagittis feugiat lectus,
      ac imperdiet urna fringilla et. In commodo nunc sed nibh consectetur sagittis. Donec sit amet sapien nec est
      tempor egestas in vel augue. Proin sodales, tortor eu mollis cursus, eros ante consequat ex, et condimentum
      massa mauris et sem.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cols-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4" class="border border-info">
    <header class="h4 border border-primary">
      Some header text
    </header>
    <div class="border border-danger">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas feugiat vitae lacus eget pretium. Donec vel
      mauris lorem. Vivamus massa enim.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cols-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4" class="border border-info">
    <header class="h4 border border-primary">
      Some really long text which is probably gonna take more than one or two lines
    </header>
    <div class="border border-danger">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas feugiat vitae lacus eget pretium. Donec vel
      mauris lorem. Vivamus massa enim, lacinia et lorem vel, porta viverra orci. Maecenas sagittis feugiat lectus,
      ac imperdiet urna fringilla et.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want to achieve the following result:

[image: expected layout]

I have tried the following without success:

Using seperate rows for the header and content, however this messes
   up the layout when going into mobile view.

Using `<br>` to create an empty line, this doesn't work.

Using the "order" class that comes with Bootstrap, however this
   didn't seem to work when wanting to mix and match row order between
   different rows on mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need another flex level.

you may use the class `d-flex` and `flex-colum`n for each columns (`.col-X`) , then use the `flex-grow-1` class for the `border-danger` div .

doc :  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row border border-success">
  <div class="cols-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4  d-flex flex-column">
    <header class="h4 border border-primary">
      Some header text
    </header>
    <div class="border border-danger  flex-grow-1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas feugiat vitae lacus eget pretium. Donec vel
      mauris lorem. Vivamus massa enim, lacinia et lorem vel, porta viverra orci. Maecenas sagittis feugiat lectus,
      ac imperdiet urna fringilla et. In commodo nunc sed nibh consectetur sagittis. Donec sit amet sapien nec est
      tempor egestas in vel augue. Proin sodales, tortor eu mollis cursus, eros ante consequat ex, et condimentum
      massa mauris et sem.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cols-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4  d-flex flex-column ">
    <header class="h4 border border-primary">
      Some header text
    </header>
    <div class="border border-danger flex-grow-1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas feugiat vitae lacus eget pretium. Donec vel
      mauris lorem. Vivamus massa enim.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cols-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4  d-flex flex-column">
    <header class="h4 border border-primary">
      Some really long text which is probably gonna take more than one or two lines
    </header>
    <div class="border border-danger  flex-grow-1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas feugiat vitae lacus eget pretium. Donec vel
      mauris lorem. Vivamus massa enim, lacinia et lorem vel, porta viverra orci. Maecenas sagittis feugiat lectus,
      ac imperdiet urna fringilla et.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

DISCLAIMER: **But to match header and content boxes in each container will require a grid layout, flex is unable to do this, only to fill entire space avalaible.**

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify my question well enough. I want the headers to be the same height so that my content divs are aligned horizontally. (refer to the image for a visual representation)... EDIT: Sorry, just read the disclaimer. Could you provide an example of how to achieve that? Using non-bootstrap is okay

Comment: @Mikael It was clear, just  added a disclaimer in my answer, boostrap cannot do this :( . that's the best compromise i can think of. bootstrap is building layout with flex.

Comment: Yeah I noticed it after posting, swear I didn't see it. A non-boostrap solution would also be greatly appreciated if you could provide an example?

Comment: Adding flex classes to the markup is not necessary for the desired result.

Comment: @Mikael a quick and dirty example from the code : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YzXwQQv i'll delete this pen later. grid example ready made : https://gridbyexample.com/  & tut : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/